# Ruby on Rails: Retrieving a friendship given two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship, self-reference

I have seen the railscast on self-referential relationships here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

I have built upon this in that I've included a 'status' field on friendships so that friendships must be requested and accepted.  'status' is a boolean -- false for not responded to yet, true for accepted.

**My problem is in coming up with a method for finding a friendship object given the current_user (I'm using Devise) and another user.**

Here is what is available to me:

```
current_user.friends              # lists people you have friended
current_user.inverse_friends      # lists people who have friended you
current_user.friendships          # lists friendships you've created
current_user.inverse_friendships  # lists friendships someone else has created with you
friendship.friend                 # returns friend in a friendship
```

**I am looking to get a method similar to the following so that I can check the status of friendships easily:**

```
current_user.friendships.with(user2).status
```

Here's my code:
user.rb

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

friendship.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

While I'm at it -- to display a user's friends I have to display both **"current_user.friends"** and **"current_user.inverse_friends"** -- is there any way to just be able to call **"current_user.friends"** and have it be a join of the two?

Comment: Why not just make a friendship a direction-neutral relationship which is either accepted or declined (status boolean)? Once a friendship has been accepted does it really matter which person originally "inititated" it?

Comment: @Andrew that would be ideal -- I do want to keep who invited who however so the sender can cancel/the receiver can accept/decline. I would love to know how to do that but it doesn't answer the main question unfortunately.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Did my answer help? If not - can you post the solution here as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass conditions to a given association thus:

```
has_many :friends, :class_name => 'User', :conditions => 'accepted IS TRUE AND (user = #{self.send(:id)} || friend = #{self.send(:id)})"'
```

Note: we use send so it doesn't evaluate the attributes until it tries to fetch them out.

If you really want the ".with(user2)" syntax, then you might be able to do it via a named_scope eg

```
Class Friendship
  named_scope :with, lambda { |user_id|
      { :conditions => { :accepted => true, :friend_id => user_id } }
    }
end
```

should allow:

```
user1.friendships.with(user2.id)
```

Note: code not tested - you may have to bugfix...

Comment: I am having trouble when running your (simplified) association: `has_many :friends, :class_name => "User", :conditions => '(user_id = #{self.send(:id)} || friend_id = #{self.send(:id)})'`.  The error I get when doing user.friends is: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users".id = 3 AND ((user_id = 3 || friend_id = 3)))`

Comment: Like I said - not tested. You'll need to update it to fit your own implementation and bugfix it. I'm guessing that your user-model uses different column-names for these... alternatively, you'll have to specify that it's "friendships".user_id etc